# Substituting Periodic Fourier series expansion equation with standing wave equation

Tags: matlab, export, fft, equation-solving

I can re-create a periodic signal using Fourier series expansion using
sin and cos waves.  But how can I adapt the equation so the equation 
will be outputted in the format of a standing wave equation.

formatting may cut off some of the information/question 
I've included a link to an image of the full question
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6576402/questions/sub_per_fou_series_expansion.jpg 
and as text file
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6576402/questions/ques1.txt

Note: I export the equation in a text format 
Here's an example/format of the equation that is currently
exported:

```
aa= 0.0000000000000000277555756156289135105908+VERTOFFmain_1+VERTOFFaad_1
+((AMPmain_1+AMPaaa_1)*0.4330127018922191872718485683435574173927)*cos((FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)*    1.0 *(t-(((-PHASEmain_1)+PHASEaac_1)/(FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)))) 
+((AMPmain_1+AMPaaa_1)*0.4330127018922194648276047246326925233006)*sin((FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)*    1.0 *(t-(((-PHASEmain_1)+PHASEaac_1)/(FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)))) 
+((AMPmain_1+AMPaaa_1)*-0.4330127018922191872718485683435574173927)*cos((FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)*    2.0 *(t-(((-PHASEmain_1)+PHASEaac_1)/(FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)))) 
+((AMPmain_1+AMPaaa_1)*-0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000)*sin((FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)*    2.0 *(t-(((-PHASEmain_1)+PHASEaac_1)/(FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1))));
```

If your interested here are some of the values I use and what the variables mean:

```
VERTOFFmain_1=0; %Vertical offset
VERTOFFaad_1=0; %Vertical offset
AMPmain_1=1; %amplitude increase 
AMPaaa_1=0; %amplitude increase
FREQmain_1=1; %Frequency increase 
FREQaab_1=0; %Frequency increase 
PHASEmain_1=0; %phase shift
PHASEaac_1=0; %phase shift
```

Here's a link explaining what a standing wave is and the equation I want to substitute in:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_wave

Here's another example with more data points showing a simple Periodic Fourier series expansion of a sin wave:

```
aa= 0.0000000000000000055511151231257830102669+VERTOFFmain_1+VERTOFFaad_1 
+((AMPmain_1+AMPaaa_1)*0.1516614837922138359083135128457797691226)*cos((FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)*    1.0 *(t-(((-PHASEmain_1)+PHASEaac_1)/(FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)))) 
+((AMPmain_1+AMPaaa_1)*0.9575529230109556255712277561542578041553)*sin((FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)*    1.0 *(t-(((-PHASEmain_1)+PHASEaac_1)/(FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)))) 
+((AMPmain_1+AMPaaa_1)*-0.0226651931432310521641326772623870056123)*cos((FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)*    2.0 *(t-(((-PHASEmain_1)+PHASEaac_1)/(FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)))) 
+((AMPmain_1+AMPaaa_1)*-0.0697562918038196477787948879267787560821)*sin((FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)*    2.0 *(t-(((-PHASEmain_1)+PHASEaac_1)/(FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)))) 
+((AMPmain_1+AMPaaa_1)*-0.0186918925876187295986863290409019100480)*cos((FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)*    3.0 *(t-(((-PHASEmain_1)+PHASEaac_1)/(FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)))) 
+((AMPmain_1+AMPaaa_1)*-0.0366849047602344491281201044330373406410)*sin((FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)*    3.0 *(t-(((-PHASEmain_1)+PHASEaac_1)/(FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)))) 
+((AMPmain_1+AMPaaa_1)*-0.0176163417098331789856224816048779757693)*cos((FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)*    4.0 *(t-(((-PHASEmain_1)+PHASEaac_1)/(FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)))) 
+((AMPmain_1+AMPaaa_1)*-0.0242468142342565640134921522985678166151)*sin((FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)*    4.0 *(t-(((-PHASEmain_1)+PHASEaac_1)/(FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)))) 
+((AMPmain_1+AMPaaa_1)*-0.0171650216811894164303797793991179787554)*cos((FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)*    5.0 *(t-(((-PHASEmain_1)+PHASEaac_1)/(FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)))) 
+((AMPmain_1+AMPaaa_1)*-0.0171650216811893852053572118165902793407)*sin((FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)*    5.0 *(t-(((-PHASEmain_1)+PHASEaac_1)/(FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)))) 
+((AMPmain_1+AMPaaa_1)*-0.0169359868831254270493680280651460634544)*cos((FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)*    6.0 *(t-(((-PHASEmain_1)+PHASEaac_1)/(FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)))) 
+((AMPmain_1+AMPaaa_1)*-0.0123047147243315942860553136029011511710)*sin((FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)*    6.0 *(t-(((-PHASEmain_1)+PHASEaac_1)/(FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)))) 
+((AMPmain_1+AMPaaa_1)*-0.0168085612357091948587672902704071020707)*cos((FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)*    7.0 *(t-(((-PHASEmain_1)+PHASEaac_1)/(FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)))) 
+((AMPmain_1+AMPaaa_1)*-0.0085643897189793712076966158974755671807)*sin((FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)*    7.0 *(t-(((-PHASEmain_1)+PHASEaac_1)/(FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)))) 
+((AMPmain_1+AMPaaa_1)*-0.0167362490935154296922693362148493179120)*cos((FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)*    8.0 *(t-(((-PHASEmain_1)+PHASEaac_1)/(FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)))) 
+((AMPmain_1+AMPaaa_1)*-0.0054379369715433292786777030869416194037)*sin((FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)*    8.0 *(t-(((-PHASEmain_1)+PHASEaac_1)/(FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)))) 
+((AMPmain_1+AMPaaa_1)*-0.0166987131473295795369704563881896319799)*cos((FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)*    9.0 *(t-(((-PHASEmain_1)+PHASEaac_1)/(FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)))) 
+((AMPmain_1+AMPaaa_1)*-0.0026448163359797938198880729032680392265)*sin((FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)*    9.0 *(t-(((-PHASEmain_1)+PHASEaac_1)/(FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)))) 
+((AMPmain_1+AMPaaa_1)*-0.0083435243106618067754354228782176505774)*cos((FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)*   10.0 *(t-(((-PHASEmain_1)+PHASEaac_1)/(FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)))) 
+((AMPmain_1+AMPaaa_1)*-0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000)*sin((FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1)*   10.0 *(t-(((-PHASEmain_1)+PHASEaac_1)/(FREQmain_1+FREQaab_1))));
```

Is their a way to adapt/substitute the Periodic Fourier series equation with the standing wave equation?

formatting may cut off some of the information/question 
I've included a link to an image of the full question
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6576402/questions/sub_per_fou_series_expansion.jpg 
and as text file
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6576402/questions/ques1.txt

Comment: "But how can I adapt the equation so the equation will be outputted in the format of a standing wave equation." by equation, do you mean the Fourier series expansion or or the equation describing the original signal? I'm not sure you can in either way as it appears you will be losing data